# Kivy: Sizing Buttons to fit wrapped text within dropdown

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, word-wrap

I'm having issues building a Kivy dropdown with word wrapping enabled for the text, such that the button widgets size accordingly to accommodate the full text.

I have followed guidance from the stack overflow thread below and similar blog post that is also linked.

- [Wrapping the text of a Kivy Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666381/wrapping-the-text-of-a-kivy-label)
- https://blog.kivy.org/2014/07/wrapping-text-in-kivys-label/

The text wraps as expected, however as the text string gets longer, there is an increasing amount of "padding" above and below the text when the button is rendered. I am unsure of what is causing this and would like to eliminate this effect.

Updated: (Edited code to be more concise to the issue. Edited image to match)

The "extra padding" is not related to the length of text, but rather the index of the loop and/or widget count added to the dropdown.

Further editing this line of code:

```
btn2 = WrapButton(text=('|' + str('long text..is long...%d' % (21-index) * index) + '|') , size_hint=(1,None))
```

To:

```
btn2 = WrapButton(text=('|' + str('long text..is long...%d' % (21-index) * index) + '|') , size_hint=(None,None),width=700)
```

(set size_hint=(none,none) rather than (1,none) and add width=700)

Eliminates the issue. I can not wrap my head around what is causing this behavior. The edited code loses the automatic width sizing for the button, and I can't imagine how a width size_hint is causing vertical "padding".

Screenshot showing issue

[image]

This code demonstrates the issue:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<WrapButton>:
    halign: "center"
    valign: "center"
    font_size: 20
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size : self.size
    height: self.texture_size[1]
''')

class WrapButton(Button):
    pass

dropdown2 = DropDown()

layout = BoxLayout(padding=0,orientation='vertical')

mainbutton2 = WrapButton(text='Select...', size_hint=(1, None),height=95,pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0})
mainbutton2.bind(on_release=dropdown2.open)
layout.add_widget(mainbutton2)

for index in range(20):
    btn2 = WrapButton(text=('|' + str('long text..is long...%d' % (21-index) * index) + '|') , size_hint=(1,None))
    btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: dropdown2.select(btn2.text))
    dropdown2.add_widget(btn2)

dropdown2.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton2, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(layout)
```

screenshot

[image]

Update:
The answer accepted below is resulting in artifacts on Android. I am working to test on other devices to rule out the device itself. Any input from the community here would be appreciated!

[Artifacts..broken Kivy install?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv2yo.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace `text_size : self.size` with `text_size : self.width, None`. Please refer to the example and output for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<WrapButton>:
    halign: "center"
    valign: "center"
    font_size: 20
    size_hint_y: None
    text_size : self.width, None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
''')


class WrapButton(Button):
    pass


dropdown2 = DropDown()

layout = BoxLayout(padding=0, orientation='vertical')

mainbutton2 = WrapButton(text='Select...', size_hint=(1, None), height=95, pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0})
mainbutton2.bind(on_release=dropdown2.open)
layout.add_widget(mainbutton2)

for index in range(20):
    btn2 = WrapButton(text=('|' + str('long text..is long...%d' % (21-index) * index) + '|'), size_hint=(1, None))
    btn2.bind(on_release=lambda btn2: dropdown2.select(btn2.text))
    dropdown2.add_widget(btn2)

dropdown2.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton2, 'text', x))

runTouchApp(layout)
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: Thanks ikolim! I'm currently testing this solution. It does appear to work with the sample code. However, I ported it to my full code base and am seeing cases where the text overflows the button vertically now. I need to make sure everything is identical and provide updated sample code should I continue to see this. Otherwise, I will mark this as the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks again, this worked as expected once I brought my code base in line with the sample code I provided.

Comment: This solution is resulting in artifacts on Android. I'll edit question and add a screenshot.