# Python kivy how to set maximum/minimum size of a widget

Tags: python, kivy, widget, max, size

If we can set window.minimum/maximum_width/height then is it possible to set a widget.minimum/maximum_width/height?

For example: [image]

The idea is the box will auto fit the words inside (I can do that base on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666381/wrapping-the-text-of-a-kivy-label)), but when we resize the screen and the text_size is wider than 70% of the app's screen the words will down the line like the picture and start writing from the left (I can't make it write from the left, cause I'm using halign="right"). (Like messenger)

Although I can do the auto fit, the problem is the box width is always 100% (default text's halign="center") that is why I'm looking for a way to set **maximum width stretch** is 70%, the box is align right and text's halign="left". (Like messenger)

**I just wonder** if we have any widget.minimum/maximum_width/height or something like that?

About the text's box, I'm currently using Button: to set up its background instead of using canvas

And if you are about to tell me to generate a BoxLayout that takes width 70% and aligns right, I just want to say that I also want this to be 2 people talking to each other (like messenger).

**update2**:
About the line below my code:

> Another bug at >>+dp(10)<<: texture_size=lambda *x:
> self.setter('size')(self,(self.texture_size[0]>>+dp(10)<<,self.texture_size[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prouc.png)+dp(10)))

I found out the reason from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/pmxoft/critical_clock_warning_too_much_iteration_done/)

I fixed that bug by replace the line:

```
width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.width, None))
```

with:

```
width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.app.root.width, None))
```

And the result is it still fits the screen but is not a wrapped text anymore.

**update1**: my code

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line,Rectangle,Ellipse
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput, FL_IS_LINEBREAK
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import copy

class MainWidget(Widget):
    request = StringProperty("Welcome")
    window_size = (305,400)
    refresh_key = False
    
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Window_minimum()
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        
    def on_size(self,*args):
        print(self.width,self.height)
        #self.ids.class_Chat_history_update
        
    def Window_minimum(self):
        Window.minimum_width,Window.minimum_height=self.window_size
        
    def on_text_validate_button(self):
        if self.ids.text_input_box.focus == True:
            self.ids.text_input_box.focus = False
            self.ids.class_Chat_history_update.Chat_history_generate(self.ids.text_input_box.text)
        
    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        # ENTER KEY CONDITION
        print(instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers)
        if len(modifiers) == 2 and modifiers[1] == 'shift' and keyboard == 13:
            self.ids.text_input_box.text=self.ids.text_input_box.text+"\n"
            
        if len(modifiers) == 2 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl' and keyboard == 13:
            self.ids.text_input_box.text=self.ids.text_input_box.text+"\n"
            
        if len(modifiers) == 1 and keyboard == 13 and self.ids.text_input_box.focus == True:
            self.ids.text_input_box.focus = False
            self.ids.class_Chat_history_update.Chat_history_generate(self.ids.text_input_box.text)
            
class Chat_history_update(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()
        l = Label(text="Welcome",size_hint=(1, None),height=("50dp"))
        self.add_widget(l)
    def Chat_history_generate(self,input_text):
        label = WrappedLabel(text=self.app.root.ids.text_input_box.text, #<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Wrapped Label getting
                                  halign="right",pos_hint={"right":.98},
                                  size_hint=(1 ,None), #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< The WrappedLabel won't work if None,None
                                  color=(1,1,1),disabled=True,background_disabled_normal='',
                                  background_color=(204/255,153/255,255/255,0.9))
        #label.height = label.texture_size[1]+dp(15)
        #label.width = label.texture_size[0]+dp(15)
        self.add_widget(label)
        
class WrappedLabel(Button): #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Main wrapped label function based on another solution
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(
            width=lambda *x: self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.width, None)),
            texture_size=lambda *x: self.setter('height')(None,self.texture_size[1]+dp(10)))
            # Another bug at >>+dp(10)<<: texture_size=lambda *x: self.setter('size')(self,(self.texture_size[0]>>+dp(10)<<,self.texture_size[1]+dp(10)))
        #self.texture_update()
        print(self.texture_size)
        # self.height = self.texture_size[1]+dp(15)
        # self.width = self.texture_size[0]+dp(15)
class Assistant(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Assistant().run()
```

.kv file

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (105/255,105/255,105/255,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size: root.size
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: "50dp"
            spacing: "10dp"
            padding: "10dp"
            Label:
                text:"Assistant"
            Button:
                text:"Edit Path"
            Button:
                text:"Setting"
        BoxLayout:
            size: self.size
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: "10dp"
            padding: "10dp"
            ScrollView: #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< history chat box
                id: chat_history_box
                Chat_history_update:
                    id: class_Chat_history_update
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    spacing: "15dp"
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1,None
                height: "40dp"
                spacing: "5dp"
                ScrollView:
                    id: scrlv
                    size_hint: .9, None
                    height: "40dp"
                    scroll_type: ['content','bars'] 
                    bar_width: '10dp'
                    TextInput:
                        id: text_input_box
                        hint_text: "Insert here"
                        #text_size: self.width*.7, None
                        size_hint: 1, None
                        height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height)
                        #multiline: False
                        cursor: 0, 0
                                        
                        on_text_validate:
                            root.on_text_validate(self)
                Button:
                    id: emit_button
                    text: "GO"
                    size_hint: .1, None
                    height: "40dp"
                    focus: True
                    background_color: (1,0,0,1) if self.focus else (0,0,1,1)
                    on_press: 
                        root.on_text_validate_button()
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_max) ?

Comment: That still does not work, I guess I'm going to post my code in the question.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem concisely and precisely.

Comment: I want my "button box size" to follow the "text size" and the "text size" to follow the change of the "window size" by converting it into wrapped text. But still working on it.

Comment: I have found out a solution for myself and going to start a new one, thanks for your help ApuCoder

Answer (score 0):

I use an if statement in the width attribute of my widget in kv files when I need to do something like this.

Eg:
width: root.width * 0.8 if root.width * 0.8 <= dp(250) else dp(250)