# Text is over spilling the viewport with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a content page in kivy that im trying to keep the text wrapped in the view port.

This is my kv code:

```
<ContentScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10

        Label:
            id: content_label
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
            font_size: '16'
```

And this is the output:

[image: The output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been already answered in another post:
[Wrapping the text of a Kivy Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666381/wrapping-the-text-of-a-kivy-label)

You need to use `text_size` to wrap text. See documentation in https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#

Here is an example built using your KV string and a basic app. If you run this, you should see text wrapped.
The `text_size: self.width, None` sets the width to adapt to the width of the application window, leaving the height unset.

```
kv_string = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    Label:
        id: content_label
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        font_size: '16'

        # generate sample text
        text: 'lorem ipsum '*1000
        # set text to adapt to the width of the window
        text_size: self.width, None
        
'''
 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    MainApp().run()
```

However, this will only wrap your text horizontally, but still clips it vertically. If you want to be able to see and scroll through the full text when it overflows vertically, you'll need to place your Label into a `ScrollView`. See https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html

Building on the example, here it is with the resulting wrapped text also scrolling vertically:

```
kv_string = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    
    ScrollView:
        # sets scrolling only vertically
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        
        Label:
            id: content_label
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
            font_size: '16'
            # resets the height of the Label
            size_hint_y: None
            # sets the height of the Label to the height of the texture
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text: 'lorem ipsum '*1000
            text_size: self.width, None
        
'''


from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    MainApp().run()
```